# Передача аргументов в callback функцию. Си

Tags: c, функции, callback, параметры

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>  

typedef bool (*pf_bool)();

bool is_less_than_10(int);
int* intarr_filter(int[], int, pf_bool, unsigned*);

int main(void) {
    int arr[] = {1, 10, 3, 6, 9, 22, 1, 20, 17, 9, 5, 14, 2, 1, 12, 11};
    int sorted_arr_length;
    int* sorted_arr = intarr_filter(arr, sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]), is_less_than_10, &sorted_arr_length);
    for (int i = 0; i < sorted_arr_length; i++) {
        printf("%d ", sorted_arr[i]);
    }
}

bool is_less_than_10(int number) {
    return number < 10;
}

int* intarr_filter(int arr[], int length, pf_bool pf, unsigned* sorted_arr_length) {
    int fits = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
        if (pf(arr[i])) fits++;
    }
    int* sorted_arr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * fits);
    *sorted_arr_length = fits;
    int current_index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
        if (pf(arr[i])) {
            sorted_arr[current_index] = arr[i];
            current_index++;
        }
    }
    return sorted_arr;
}
```

Есть функция `intarr_filter`, которая фильтрует значения массива с помощью переданной функции и возвращает указатель на новый массив, хранящий только подходящие значения. Я могу спокойно передать функцию `is_less_than_10` и получить ожидаемый результат. Но что, если мне нужна для фильтрации функция, принимающая несколько аргументов? Что, если у меня есть такая функция:

```
bool is_less(int number1, int number2) {
    return number1 < number2;
}
```

Что, если я не знаю заранее, какое число мне нужно будет для сравнения? Как мне передать несколько аргументов для callback функции, которую я передаю в `intarr_filter`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавить в вашу callback-функцию параметр типа `void *`, через который в нее будет передаваться указатель на произвольные "пользовательские данные". Добавить параметр типа `void *` в `intarr_filter` тоже - она должна просто насквозь передавать этот параметр в callback при каждом его вызове. Через этот `void *` вы сможете передавать из вызывающего кода в callback все, что угодно.

```
typedef bool (*pf_bool)(int, void *);

int* intarr_filter(int arr[], int length, pf_bool pf, unsigned* sorted_arr_length,
                   void *user_data) 
{
  ...
  if (pf(arr[i], user_data)) 
  ...
}

bool is_less_than(int lhs, void *user_data) 
{
  int rhs = *(const int *) user_data;
  return lhs < rhs;
}

int main(void) 
{
  ...
  int rhs = 10;
  intarr_filter(arr, sizeof arr / sizeof *arr, is_less_than, &sorted_arr_length, &rhs);
  ...
  rhs = 42;
  intarr_filter(arr, sizeof arr / sizeof *arr, is_less_than, &sorted_arr_length, &rhs);
  ...
}
```

или даже (если ваши пользовательские данные помещаются в разрядность `intptr_t`)

```
bool is_less_than(int lhs, void *user_data) 
{
  int rhs = (int)(intptr_t) user_data;
  return lhs < rhs;
}

int main(void) 
{
  ...
  intarr_filter(arr, sizeof arr / sizeof *arr, is_less_than, &sorted_arr_length, 
    (void *)(intptr_t) 10);
  ...
  intarr_filter(arr, sizeof arr / sizeof *arr, is_less_than, &sorted_arr_length, 
    (void *)(intptr_t) 42);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, это решает мою проблему. Но сразу возникает новая: что, если я теперь буду использовать функцию, не требующую дополнительных аргументов? (Например, всё ту же `is_less_than_10`). Функция `intarr_filter` будет требовать передачи дополнительных аргументов. Я могу, конечно, передать, что-угодно (хоть указатель на массив, который передаётся первым аргументов), на результат это не повлияет, но выглядит не очень. Есть альтернатива? (Может, какой-то пустой указатель, на "ничего"?)

Comment: @Don2Quixote Ну естественным выбором в таких случаях будет передавать null-указатель. Но что-то передавать придется всегда.

Comment: спасибо большое.

Comment: `uintptr_t`, наверное.

Comment: @0andriy: Почему это вдруг? По сути задачи параметр - знаковый.

Comment: Указатель на память эквивалентен беззнаковому типу. Я ошибаюсь?

Comment: @0andriy: Указатель - это указатель. Он не *эквивалентен* вообще никакому целочисленному типу.

Comment: Откуда тогда ноги растут об _unsigned long always has enough space to keep a pointer_?

Comment: @0andriy Это - чушь. И при чем здесь вдруг `unsigned long` если речь шла о `uintptr_t`? Если бы мне захотелось рассмотреть содержимое указателя - адрес - в целочисленном виде, я бы сам использовал именно беззнаковый `uintptr_t`. Но в данном случае задача состоит совсем в другом.

Comment: Вы пишете, если параметр помещается в `intptr_t`, я утверждаю, что более корректно говорить о беззнаковом `uintptr_t`. По одной простой причине — физические адреса памяти не могут быть отрицательными в нашем мире. А называть это чушью надо иметь веские основания, коих я не заметил. (`unsigned long` в до `*ptr_t` эпоху, что, впрочем, не отменяет и современные реалии)

Comment: @0andriy: Во-первых, слово "чушь" относилось только к конкретному утверждению про `unsigned long`. Это действительно чушь. Откуда тут вообще внезапно взялся `unsigned long`? Во-вторых, о каких еще "физических адресах памяти" вы ведете речь? В моем примере не используются никакие "физических адреса памяти" даже близко. Переменная типа "указатель" используется для хранения и передачи отвлеченного знакового целочисленного значения, возможно отрицательного. Никаких "адресов памяти" тут нет.

Comment: А указатель в никуда? Про `unsigned long` я вам уже объяснил, перестаньте за него цепляться, лучше разберитесь с неточностями в тексте.

Comment: @0andriy: Ваше объяснение про `unsigned long` мне совершенно не понятно, не говоря уже о том, что никакое "объяснение" не может поменять того факта, что `unsigned long` тут совершенно ни при чем. Что касается "указателя в никуда" - да это именно "указатель в никуда". В общем случае использованный мною прием ведет к неопределенному поведению независимо от того, какой тип был использован в преобразовании. Он может работать только на конкретных платформах, явно позволяющих подобное.

Comment: `unsigned long`, раз у вас всё ещё фиксация, является типом, который помещается в регистр на железном уровне. Вы, видимо, далеки от железа, поэтому не понимаете очевидных вещей, как и несильной абстракции языка Си.

Comment: @0andriy: Вы продолжаете генерировать какую-то необъяснимую несусветную чепуху не по теме. Я больше не вижу смысла продолжать дискуссию.